# what is the most efficient way to implement full text search on a sqlite database

Tags: c#, full-text-search, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am using sqlite database for storing data. One of the table contains fields like name, summary, description, location etc. I want to implement full text search on this table i.e. I want to search the given word in all columns of the table. What is the best way to do this? I have a reference to sqlite.data.dll in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SQLite FTS3 and FTS4 Extensions ? see here: [SQLite FTS3 and FTS4 Extensions](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html)

Comment: I already read this. But as I mentioned in my question, I am only using sqlite.data.dll. How can I add FTS3/4 module into that dll?

Comment: Do you mean System.Data.SQLite.dll? if so, FTS3 support is builtin I think.